# copy date from one table to another It becomes part of table on the Delivery Date

Tags: sql, ms-access

Table 1: ProductDistribution

```
ProductID
DistrubutionCentrsID
ProductName
DateOrdered
DateDelivered
```

copy in other table on the Delivery Date.
Table 2: Products

```
ProductID
ProductName
DateOrdered
DateDelivered
```

I wrote this,

```
INSERT INTO ProductDistribution
SELECT ProductID, ProductName, DateOrdered 
FROM Products 
WHERE DateDelivered= getdate()
```

but it gives me an error:

> undefine funcation getdate() in expersion

Comment: it is about MS ACCESS 2010 .i want to set criteria on the base of extend date

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     INSERT INTO ProductDistribution (ProuductID, ProductName , DateOrdered)
     AS
     SELECT ProductID, ProductName, DateOrdered
     FROM Products
     WHERE DateDelivered = getdate()
```